# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn perde valor selecionado

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um DataGridView e faço o bind dele através de uma lista. Até aqui tudo bem...

Agora quero adicionar um combobox (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dinamicamente com base numa outra lista.

Na primeira linha de código faço o bind da minha lista perfeitamente. Abaixo dela tenho o código pra preencher o meu combobox. Após mudar o foco da linha do datagridview o combobox fica com o valor nulo.

Eu gostaria de poder definir um índice pra que esse combo não venha com o valor nulo e que ele não perca a seleção que escolhi. 
É possível fazer isso ?

```
dgvLotes.DataSource = lotesDB.GetLotesByStatus(ValorRadioSelecionado());

List<Produto> listProdutos = new List<Produto>();
        listProdutos.Add(new Produto(){Id = 1, Nome = "Produto 1"});
        listProdutos.Add(new Produto() { Id = 2, Nome = "Produto 2" });
        listProdutos.Add(new Produto() { Id = 3, Nome = "Produto 3" });
        listProdutos.Add(new Produto() { Id = 4, Nome = "Produto 4" });

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboBoxColumn.DataSource = listProdutos.ToList();
        comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Id";
        comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Nome";

        dgvLotes.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
```

Comment: Como assim definir um índice? Ja tentou utilizar listProdutos.SelectedIndex  = 0 depois de fazer o bind no COMBOBOX?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não sei se entendi sua questão, mas se entendi, nesse caso você deveria usar o ItemTemplate.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:DataGrid ID="datagrid" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="datagrid_ItemDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdown">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>      
</div>
```

No código você vai popular o dropdown no momento em que ele vai criando as linhas no evento ItemDataBound:

```
  protected void datagrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //encontra o dropdown 
        DropDownList itemDropDown = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dropdown");

        //popular o dropdown list com seus valores
        //...

        //caso precise de acessar algum dado que já esteja no datagrid em alguma coluna.
        var dataitem = e.Item.DataItem;
    }
```

Então item a item você vai populando o que quiser dentro do ItemTemplate. Pode ser um DropDown, pode ser um CheckBox, enfim, o que você quiser. E caso precise acessar uma key qualquer de dado que esteja dando bind na linha, use o e.Item.DataItem;